# help with error ClientAuthError: User login is required. For silent calls, request must contain either sid or login_hint

Tags: microsoft-graph, msal

I'm using MSAL.js to acquire a silent token and it works ok when i login
See my snippet code below

```
  var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    //console.log(email);
var upn = getUserEmailByLoginName(userid);

var config = {  
    auth: {  
        clientId: "",  
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/techie.onmicrosoft.com"  
        redirectUri: "someUrl",
    },  
    cache: {  
        cacheLocation: "localStorage"          
    }  
};  
var requestPermissionScope = {  
     scopes: ["user.read"],
     loginHint: upn,--setting the email address here e.g joe@xyz.com (is this the loginHint?
   //extraQueryParameters: {domain_hint: 'organizations'}  
};
```

The issue i'm facing though is when another user logs in the get this error below

> ClientAuthError: User login is required. For silent calls, request
> must contain either sid or login_hint

In regards to the loginHint. What value do we need? Is it an email address?

In this [article](https://pub.dev/documentation/msal_js/latest/msal_js/AuthRequest/loginHint.html)

it says prefered_username. But what is it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: No hint no reply for 20 days :(
Anyone can help or hint